# Boolean Hole Difference causes messy subdivsion

Tags: modifiers

[image]I am trying to make a boolean cylinder cut into a mesh, but no matter what I try, the results are messy when I try to add a subdivision modifier.
Here is a screenshot. I tried to make loopcuts to prevent wacko subdivision, but failed.
Thx so much!
[image]

Comment: that diagonal line seems to connect to one of the inner circles, not the orange one you selected. It looks like you have some overlapping faces there. Try redoing the boolean operation and make sure your cylinder is long enough to really pierce the object.

Comment: on another note ... if you plan on using subdivision, consider reducing the edges of the zylinder to about 12 or even less. If you integrate it correctly subdivision will take care of the rest. See this tutorial series: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi87Dap_WOc&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHJVJF3T3CFUAZ6z11jKg6a

Comment: the cylinder pierced through alright, but for some reason these diagonal lines keep popping up again. I will try to include more pictures of the steps I took. Thx for helping.

Comment: those diagonal lines are there for a reason, blender cannot handle faces with in your case 32+4 edges. therefore it inserts the diagonal lines to reduce the amount to 16+2 edges wich is a lot aswell. so you have to step in an reduce the maximal amount of edges of the faces around your zylinder to 4. subdivision makes a mess of faces with that much edges.

Comment: So... I need to use a cylinder with less edges?

Comment: either that or insert a massive amount of loopcuts around your big object so every edgevertex of your cylinder becomes part of your big mesh. since you are modeling in low poly reduce the edges of the zylinder. but you have to connect the vertices of the edges either way. onyl with less edges you need to make less loop cuts around your big object.